# Calculating an acceleration from 3 axis MEMS

Tags: acceleration, accelerator-physics

I installed a MEMD sensor on a motor that I can control the motor speed.
I'm recording the information from the sensor (x, y, z)

I'm trying to compare if the MEMS sensor reading is ad the same as my motor speed. But I don't know how to convert the data from the 3 Axis MEMS

For example
I set my motor speed to 28.84 RPM, I have the data from the MEMS sensor (as a X,Y,Z array)

How i can convert the data to RPM or vice versa  to be able to compare the reading to the actual motor speed .

thanks

Comment: Would Engineering SE be a better home for your question?

Comment: What is the axis of your motor in the xyz co-ordinate system? What is the direction of gravity?